# Set USB 3.0 controller to USB 2.0 only

Tags: usb

I have a Sony Vaio VPCF1 machine, with only USB 3.0 ports.  I have a USB 2.0 device that doesn't seem to work on these ports. (Connecting to another machine with both USB 2.0 ports and another set of USB 3.0 ports, it connects only to the USB 2.0).

So I wondered if there is a way to set the USB controller to USB 2.0 mode or something?

Comment: Some bios settings allow you to disable usb 3.0, have a look in the bios.

Comment: Can you try using a USB 2.0 hub?  That might trick the device into behaving.

Comment: I have a related question if someone is interested in answering: [Maximizing speed of USB 2.0 clients on USB 3.0 hub](http://superuser.com/questions/1074183/maximizing-speed-of-usb-2-0-clients-on-usb-3-0-hub)

Answer (score 3):

A [USB FAQ](http://www.everythingusb.com/compatibility.html#2) says

> Will my existing peripherals still work? How will they co-exist? 
>   The good news is that USB 3.0 has been carefully planned from the start to peacefully co-exist with USB 2.0. First of all, while USB 3.0 specifies new physical connections and thus new cables to take advantage of the higher speed capability of the new protocol, the connector itself remains the same rectangular shape with the four USB 2.0 contacts in the exact same location as before. Five new connections to carry receive and transitted data independently are present on USB 3.0 cables and only come into contact when mated with a proper SuperSpeed USB connection.

[Datapro say](http://www.datapro.net/techinfo/usb_3_explained.html#USB_Backwards_Compatibility)

> Since USB has proven itself to be the overwhelming favorite interface, a crucial pillar of the USB 3.0 specification addresses how the SuperSpeed interface must remain compatible with the millions of existing USB computers and devices in the marketplace. For the most part, it's good news: **all USB 2.0 devices will work on USB 3.0 hardware**, and (nearly) all USB 3.0 devices will work on USB 2.0 hardware.

The [USB Implementers Forum](http://www.usb.org/about) (who develop the USB spec) [say](http://www.usb.org/developers/ssusb)

> SuperSpeed USB is backwards compatible with USB 2.0. Devices interoperate with USB 2.0 platforms. Hosts support USB 2.0 legacy devices.

All USB 3.0 ports *should* work with USB 2.0 peripherals.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so maybe it's a driver problem with my device then.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same laptop. The drivers for most of the functions of the laptop do not work with a vanilla Windows 7 install. Instead you need to go here: http://www.sony-asia.com/support/download/374988
And get the ones you need.